# How to push the values to blade template in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to push an array to the blade template in laravel 4
Controller name: AdminController

```
public function listCompanies()
{
    $companyObj = new company();
    $companies = $companyObj->getCompanies();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main',$companies);
}
```

Template name: main.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
     @yield('content')
     @foreach ($companies as $company)
         <p>This is company {{ $company['name'] }}</p>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

The error I am getting is:
Undefined variable: companies (View: C:\wamp\www\larvel-project\laravel\app\views\admin\main.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

The view is expecting to receive an associative array which includes the index 'companies' and will turn that into $companies.

Any of the following should work for you:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main', ['companies' => $companies]);

$this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main', compact('companies'));

$this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main')->with('companies', $companies);
```

Comment: do I need to add $companies instead of companies

Comment: Yes, it's ['companies' => $companies]

Comment: Apologies, yes. Examples 1 and 3 edited for clarity.